# 3DEP WMS hillshade zoom/rendering issue?

Tags: qgis, wms, zoom, hillshade

Edit: This appears to be an issue with the 3DEP program or ImageServer itself. The same unrendered areas appear in the [ArcGIS Online Map Viewer](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Felevation.nationalmap.gov%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2F3DEPElevation%2FImageServer&source=sd) and in https://apps.nationalmap.gov/3depdem/.

---

I'm running into an issue with QGIS 3.36.0 where, when I zoom in roughly past 1:1000000 scale, chunks of two hillshade layers (3DEP Elevation imported via WMS) stop rendering.

It's always the same chunks, and nothing I do seems to affect them (changing layer or project CRS, removing and re-adding the WMS, etc.).

Here is the Network Logger output during an attempted zoom in and failure to load. The tiles that aren't loaded don't even seem to generate any kind of message at all.

A picture of the result is attached—the bright green blocks at the bottom are where the hillshade layers stop appearing.

Has anyone else run into this issue/know what might be the issue?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Reminds me of some limitations on the number of tiles that can be loaded. I don't remember if it was on QGIS size or on the WMS server, but you should probably look for similar issues/max number of loaded tiles topics.

Comment: What is shown in the network logs?

Comment: @IanTurton I've added a picture of what appears to be an example of the failure to load via the Network Logger. If there's a better way to do that let me know—I'm relatively inexperienced with both QGIS and StackExchange.

Comment: QGis has a network debug plugin that should show you just the failed requests